# local proxy port forward error with SSH: SSS_SSH_knownhostsProxy: connection refused

Tags: ssh, rhel, proxy

I am using redhat enterprise edition 8.9 where I am trying to connect to remote server via local proxy method:

When I run the command in the shell:

> ssh 127.0.0.1 -p 35856

I get the below error:

```
SSS_SSH_knownhostsProxy: connection to host 127.0.0.1 port 46464: connection refused
kex_exchange_identification: connection closed by remote host
```

I also checked the file under /var/lib/sss/pubconf/known_hosts but nothing is there.

Not sure what I need to make change and where and which setting in which file.

When I try to login directly to the remote server from local host via SSH, it works (i.e ssh ), it does not work via localproxy port forward.

In a nutshell, I am trying to use local proxy forward to ssh into remote server.